# Spring Boot -- ClassNotFoundException, but the main class exists

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, jsp

I am going through a tutorial to run a JSP from Spring Boot.  I am getting this error trace, even though the class I have designated as the main class exists.  Here is the exception trace, which I have edited for space.

```
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hellokoding.springboot.view.Application
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:521)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:553)
        at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.hellokoding.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-helloworld</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.hellokoding.springboot.view.Application</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Have you correctly built the artifact?

Comment: Yes, and I still get the exception.

Comment: Sometimes, you should ensure that the main class in the folder structure, like `src/main/java/yourpackagename/` and `application.properties` in `src/main/resource/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirm file was complied at expected location by expanding your generated artifact. You should see your Application.class file at:

/target/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/com/hellokoding/springboot/view/Application.class

It should be annotated with @SpringBootApplication contain the following method signature

public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: Ah, there's the problem.  It's not there.  In fact, Maven isn't even compiling anything.  How can I correct the problem?

Comment: The tutorial I was going through had a link to the code at GitHub.  I downloaded that code and ran the code successfully.

Comment: For me, this all fits, still not found